# Running Bitcoin on command-line-only system

Tags: bitcoin-core, websites

I want to run a Bitcoin client on a command-line-only system (Amazon EC2). Is there some specific command-line parameters I should use in order to run the main client without the GUI, or will it run properly without any parameters? How do I later check the status of the client (check number of connections, balance, etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run it as a daemon type:

```
$ bitcoind -daemon
bitcoin server starting
$
```

You can then use the [API calls](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) to do whatever you want:

```
$ bitcoind getblockcount
153407
$ bitcoind getconnectioncount
20
```

Comment: When I run that, I get "error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)". Do I need to pass those values on the command line?